# MongoDB query with a list of conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an API that does batch search, the calling application calls the API with a list of criteria:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "dob": "1998-11-27"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "dob": "1994-11-27"
  }
]
```

I what to search the collection for this users and return an array back to the user.

right now, I'm looping thru the criteria:

```
req.body.forEach(function (person, index) {
  db.collection('Test').find({ "GivenName": person.firstName, "Surname": person.lastName, "Date_of_Birth": person.dob}).toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(result)
  })
});
```

I'm stuggling with, how do I return the results to in the response - `res.send(result);`? or can I do this with the foreach loop?

Comment: What do you want to return? What `req.body` has?

Comment: You could use `Promise` or `async/await` for individual iteration which is `async`. Though this can be done in a single query with multiple [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) in `.find()`

Comment: @Ashh req.body is the passed in criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a dynamic query using javascript map, and use it with [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator. This way you can get the result with only one db access.

Sample route:

```
router.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let queryArray = req.body.map(person => {
      return {
        GivenName: person.firstName,
        Surname: person.lastName,
        Date_of_Birth: person.dob
      };
    });

    const db = req.app.locals.db;

    const result = await db
      .collection("Test")
      .find({ $or: queryArray })
      .toArray();

    res.status(200).send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});
```

Sample documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1cb0b0a6e44d18fcf23d7b"),
    "GivenName" : "Bill",
    "Surname" : "Smith",
    "Date_of_Birth" : "1995-07-17",
    "gender" : "Male"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1cb0b0a6e44d18fcf23d7a"),
    "GivenName" : "Jane",
    "Surname" : "Doe",
    "Date_of_Birth" : "1994-11-27",
    "gender" : "Female"
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1cb0b0a6e44d18fcf23d79"),
    "GivenName" : "John",
    "Surname" : "Doe",
    "Date_of_Birth" : "1998-11-27",
    "gender" : "Male"
}
```

Request body:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "dob": "1998-11-27"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "dob": "1994-11-27"
  }
]
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e1cb0b0a6e44d18fcf23d79",
        "GivenName": "John",
        "Surname": "Doe",
        "Date_of_Birth": "1998-11-27",
        "gender": "Male"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e1cb0b0a6e44d18fcf23d7a",
        "GivenName": "Jane",
        "Surname": "Doe",
        "Date_of_Birth": "1994-11-27",
        "gender": "Female"
    }
]
```

Note that if you have many documents in your collection, this query may be slow, so you can consider to create a compound index at GivenName, Surname and Date_of_Birth fields.

Comment: @capiono doesn't this answer your question?